# Magento 2.2.3 - Sort product collection by custom price

Tags: catalog, product-collection, sorting, magento2.2.3, custom-prices

I want to sort my `product custom price` instead of Magento default price. By default product price is '0'.

I overwrite `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php`.

I set my custom product price in `public function setCollection($collection){ ... }`.

I do not set a custom price for product collection. When I print product collection after *set price*. It always displays '0'.

Here is my code,

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int) $this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    foreach ($this->_collection as $key => $value) {
        $price = 20;
        $value->setPrice($price);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

How to set custom price in product collection(`$this->_collection`)?

And how to *sort product by custom price*?

Comment: I also got the same issue. did you find any solution for this?